# FullCalendar unselect() does not remove temporary event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, interaction, fullcalendar-5

I am working on a Full Calendar v5.7.2 integration and have been struggling for quite some time to get the *temporary* event removed from the calendar.

Here is the process I follow:

- Click and drag to select a new event
- Have a bootstrap modal popup
- Close the modal
- Event should be removed

Even when I execute `calendar.unselect();` from the debugger console, the temp event does not get removed.
The [unselect](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselect-callback) callback is called but the event stays in the calendar.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: `unselect` removes a user selection. If you actually went ahead and added an event, that won't remove it. Due to the lack of code provided, it's unclear what you've actually done. Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue please, and then we can assist you properly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Oh I see so the unselect is for the background selection, not the actual event that's added. I managed to understand this by removing the actual last event of the calendar. I will try and reproduce my case in a reproducible example.

Comment: Oh I see what I had wrond, I had a dangling calendar.addEvent() lost in the code. After re-reading everything I managed to have it sorted.